# Where to find grad school acceptance rates?

Tags: graduate-admissions, mathematics

I've been searching (without luck) for the kind of information that was very easy to find when I was applying to undergrad; namely, information such as acceptance rates and median GRE scores of accepted applicants. I'm planning on applying to pure math grad school. Is there some online resource for finding this information?

Update: I found one resource for this information, but I'm not sure how accurate it is. After clicking on the colleges it had acceptance rates for most of them; search filters are on the left. http://www.petersons.com/graduate-schools/SearchResults.aspx?id=MTRkODRkYWEtODEwZC00OWU3LTk3NDUtYjliNDdhZTYxZDk5

Comment: Interesting question.  Undergraduate admissions are handled by dedicated admissions staff, whereas graduate admissions are normally determined by a committee of the department's faculty.  This generally means that graduate admissions are less likely to have the same sort of systematic marketing, record-keeping, and transparency.  I would not be too surprised if many (most?) departments simply don't make this information publicly available.

Comment: [UPenn's outdated but still helpful page on their average GRE scores](http://www.math.upenn.edu/grad/graddata.html). A 170 (max score) on the new GRE is equivalent to a 780 on the old GRE due to the smaller buckets. A 168 would probably be the minimum score for competitiveness. According to US News and World Report, Penn's mathematics program is #17 based on GRE scores and other factors, so it is likely that average GRE scores for the top 30 are pretty much 170 on Math.

Comment: Some good resources are mathematicsgre.com and thegradcafe.com - at both websites, people will post their GRE scores, the schools they applied to and whether they were accepted or not.

Comment: Have you tried emailing them and asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not directly answers you question but I found it useful when applied to grad schools in the past. [GradCafe](http://www.thegradcafe.com/survey/) results shows different applications results for institutes. Applicants usually put their GRE scores and GPA along with the decision.

Most importantly, some applicants communicate with their school and write something really useful as a note (like # of application received/accepted/rejected).